# Room Migration Error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, android-room, android-database

I have used a model inside a model in my app's Room Database.
It is like this:

I have a **PackageModel**

```
@Entity
public class PackageModel {

@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = false)
@NonNull
String package_id;

String location mobil,isChecked;
```

And another model:

```
@Entity
public class DeliveryJsonModel {

@PrimaryKey @NonNull
String deliveryJsonid;

@Embedded
PackageModel packageModel;

String ktr_datotid, ktrpkt_type,tg_aarsak_kode, aarsak_nr, bruker, sig_fil_ref, id_type;
boolean skade, isPackageScanned, isNotFound;
```

In this second model, I am using `@embedded` tag to use `PackagModel`
The Problem started when i added a column `deleted` in my PackageModel. Since I am using PackageModel in my second model, it is expecting the `deleted` column there also.

So I wrote the igration for that as:

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE DeliveryJsonModel ADD COLUMN deleted INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0");
```

But my application is throwing a Room error saying that

> Room can not handle the migration.
>
> Expected:
>       TableInfo{name='DeliveryJsonModel', columns={deleted=Column{name='deleted', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
>
> Found:
>       TableInfo{name='DeliveryJsonModel', columns={deleted=Column{name='deleted', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

As you can see the deleted value htat is found is**false**, I don't understand why is this happening, I have set the default value to 0 in my migrations.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: why don't you just add TEXT column in json and store there?